# Can a same job with different build parameters be executed in Jenkins by different users

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Job named `CheckStatus` which performs the operation of checking the status of different applications. I have a build in parameter which shows the list of all applications, say `AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF`.

I come and start the job with application AAA as build parameter to check the status. Is it possible for others users who have access, to run the same job with same or different applications (like AAA, CCC, DDD) as a parameter and get the output?

Does this kind of execution supported by Jenkins. If not, how can we make sure that this type of parallel execution of the same job with same or different users be supported.

Comment: Are you asking about user-access, or are you asking about running multiple jobs in parallel?

Comment: same job running by different users parallely

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Each freestyle job has a property you can set that to prevent concurrent execution of the job. If that is not checked, then multiple builds can run at the same time, regardless of parameter.

Comment: Oh great. thank you. is there any limit to execute multiple builds ?

Comment: Only limited by the number of agent executors available.

Comment: we are around 60 people and anyone can execute the job whenever they need even when multiple people are already running the job.. is that what you are saying ?.. any default value for the agent executors ?

Answer (score 1):

You can run a job concurrently on jenkins. Just check this option in your job configuration:
[image]

Make sure you have enough executors when you check this. 
You can also restrict the number of executions with [Throttle Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin). Refer to [this documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/throttle-concurrent-builds-plugin/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: thanks for the info. will go through the documentation and link.